# The remote server returned an error: (401) : Linked In API

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm have created a small wrapper to access Linked In API, the parameters that I'm passing to that are the following:

```
[oauth_verifier, 88600]
[oauth_token, xxxx]
[oauth_version, 1.0]
[oauth_nonce, xxx]
[oauth_timestamp, xxxxx]
[oauth_signature_method, HMAC-SHA1]
[oauth_consumer_key, xxxxxx]
[oauth_consumer_secret, xxxxxx]
[oauth_signature, xxx+xxxxxxxxxxx]
```

the exception that I'm getting is the following:
"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

I'm trying to access that via web request which works perfectly for twitter you can take a look to the following code:

```
public static OAuthTokenResponse GetAccessToken(string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, string requestToken, string verifier, string getAccessTokenUrl, string realM)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(consumerKey))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("consumerKey");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(consumerSecret))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("consumerSecret");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestToken))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("requestToken");
        }



        WebRequestBuilder builder = new WebRequestBuilder(
            new Uri(getAccessTokenUrl),
            HTTPVerb.GET,
            new OAuthTokens { ConsumerKey = consumerKey, ConsumerSecret = consumerSecret });
        builder.Realm = realM;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(verifier))
        {
            builder.Parameters.Add("oauth_verifier", verifier);
        }


        builder.Parameters.Add("oauth_token", requestToken);

        string responseBody;

        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse webResponse = builder.ExecuteRequest();

            responseBody = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (WebException wex)
        {
            throw new Exception(wex.Message, wex);
        }

        OAuthTokenResponse response = new OAuthTokenResponse();
        response.Token = Regex.Match(responseBody, @"oauth_token=([^&]+)").Groups[1].Value;
        response.TokenSecret = Regex.Match(responseBody, @"oauth_token_secret=([^&]+)").Groups[1].Value;
        response.UserId = long.Parse(Regex.Match(responseBody, @"user_id=([^&]+)").Groups[1].Value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        response.ScreenName = Regex.Match(responseBody, @"screen_name=([^&]+)").Groups[1].Value;
        return response;
    }
```

I get the error when I hit the execute request.

the web request builder do the following:

```
public HttpWebResponse ExecuteRequest()
{
        HttpWebRequest request = PrepareRequest();
  return (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
```

I guess I'm missing a parameter in the request, any Ideas?

Comment: The clue is in the error "401 - Unauthorized", your consumer key/secret combination are probably wrong.

Comment: @James the combination are correct I have tried using the form provided by linked in  and I got the all the values needed, http://developer.linkedin.com/oauth-test-console

Comment: Hmm interesting, is there a proxy sitting in front of your API?

Comment: No we just do the web request plain! no proxies, I guess _I'm missing a parameter, I think I need to know what open oath handles the AuthorizedTokenResponse accessTokenResponse = consumer.ProcessUserAuthorization(); I guess it could be usefull to see how they handle that process, because I don't want to use .net open oauth, I want to use a simple web request (which under the hood I guess is the same)

Comment: I would suggest using a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to inspect the request and make sure your request is in fact sending the correct data. Considering things like HTML encoding etc.

Comment: I cant use a http debugger doing a web request

Comment: why not? Fiddler acts as a proxy and intercepts any web requests (from applications or browsers).

Comment: I can't get the request in the list...

Comment: What sort of app are you firing the request form? Is it a web/desktop?

Comment: that's a web application but the code is in different layer but anyway it references system.web

Comment: it doesn't matter what *layer* the code is being triggered in, Fiddler inserts itself as a proxy on your internet settings so anything that uses Wininet to communicate with the web should appear in fiddler.